# Can I easily see my review accuracy somewhere?

Tags: support, feature-request, review-queues, suggested-edits, triage

This question relates mostly [triage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/triage) and [suggested-edits](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/suggested-edits)

I can find my review history but I can not find an easy way to find out if the consensus of some review matches the judgment I committed on my review.

I mean that if I judged some post `Unsalvageable` was the consensus of the review same or perhaps `Looks OK` instead and I might have missed some aspect totally in that review?

Currently my self-control process goes like:

1. Open a review - one by one - in the history page.
2. Check the status of completion for review.
3. If review is completed then compare reviews consensus to my review judgment.

Is there any easier way to do this?

For example and as a possible feature request: if in the review history page, right after the column that shows my own judgment, was another column that would show the consensus it would be quite easy to see accuracy.

**NOTE**: I understand that this accuracy thing I am after can not be taken as "final truth" or so but it still gives me some aspect to my own actions.

Comment: Looks like the time for an SEDE query.

Comment: I have a feeling that rene's done a userscript for this...

Comment: @JonClements yes, I have [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/248338/adding-the-consensus-to-reviews-history/251508#251508)

Comment: @rene Master of userscript here...

Comment: @rene Seems that it is exactly what I need. Just not yet able to get it working, first time trying to install a user script.

Comment: @pirho it relies on the client side html structure of the review pages. If something is changed on the SE site, it might bark. I think last time I checked was back in december when it worked for at least two queues. Let me know how it goes. Oh and don't use GreaseMonkey on FF. Use ViolentMonkey or TamperMonkey on any other decent browser.

Comment: @rene  If it is not too much problem could you - or anyone - at some point confirm if it works or not currently? Using FF57 it is activated on review/history pages (under _User scripts for this tab_) so I guess the installation went OK with GreaseMonkey.

Comment: I checked in Chrome/Win10 with TamperMonkey and there it works. I can only look into this tonight, SE day wise.

Comment: @rene Thanks, I changed Grease- to TamperMonkey (still FF57), Triage history works now like a charm :) In suggested edits history is shown at start three dots for each row then when calculating it just clears those dots but sets no status.

Comment: @pirho Ok, I'll look into the suggested edits in the next 6 to 8 something.

Comment: @rene I'll hold my breath until then ;) Script is otherwise awesome.

Comment: I would not hold my breath if I were you. I don't want to be responsible for the tragic death of a valuable SO user ....

Comment: Reviews are subjective. "Accuracy" isn't something that can be measured automatically.

Comment: @rene *`If something is changed on the SE site, it might bark.`* It might **bark** eh? I'd like to see that!

Comment: @jpmc26 Yes, that is why there is a **NOTE** at the end of my post. It is just something that gives me some insight.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, you can't see that easily, at least not with what the site offers.

I did write a userscript that is available on Meta Stack Exchange as an response on this feature request: [Adding the consensus to review's history](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/251508/158100). Consider supporting that feature request to help the SE team prioritizing.

Said userscript can be installed from [GreasyFork](https://greasyfork.org/en/scripts/9996-match-against-peers-in-review).

There was a small bug in version 0.4 for how the suggested edits review history was processed. That bug is fixed in 0.5 and available for download.

Comment: Tim Post was thinking once about doing something like a dashboard to see your impact on the queues.

Comment: @Braiam oh, that sounds cool!

Comment: @rene Thanks for the fix. Just need to take care to not refresh history page too often. Already exceeded my rate limit yesterday. And: I guess supporting = upvote?

Comment: @pirho supporting can be an upvote but also a good edit to bump it / make it more clear or offer a bounty, or leave a comment to explain how it will help you be better at reviewing content, share a link among your peers, talk about it in chat. I'm not giving a voting advice, it is your vote, that is for you to decide.

Comment: Sorry for asking question here but can you say where can I see final result of a triage review? In review, there are 2 unsalvageable and 3 requires edit votes and review is completed. Is requires edit correct answer?

Comment: @Dharmaraj That depends on the review. Most often requires editing is not correct. Based on your info the review outcome would have requires editing and the post would have been sent to the Help & Improvement queue. If it turned out no-one could edit that post into shape and instead it got closed, requires editing wasn't the right choice for that post. My consensus script is only an assistance in self-evaluation.

Comment: Ok thanks for the information. One last question, do Everyone gets audit or test questions forever or at some reputation point they stop appearing?

Comment: On average every 50 reviews the system will present a reviewer with two audits. That is for everyone, no matter how much you reviewed or how much rep you have. When you have failed an audit the frequency goes up, to roughly one every 10 reviews but that is based on observation, not that I know the exact algorithm,